Getting AAD App ID conflict error while triggering activity notification in Microsoft Teams
We are trying to resubmit our app in Microsoft Teams for an update. During the review period, we are getting app conflict error while triggering activity notifications.
Following is the error message:
Found multiple applications with the same AAD App ID 'ff682f83-2e00-4acb-8010-a3d7b4f3c832' - a Teams Application ID is required to resolve which application is correct.
Since we have two app records in Microsoft Teams admin, one for the currently public version(1.0.0) and another for the newly uploaded version(2.0.0), which is under review. Both the apps have the same AAD App ID and it is creating this conflict. And we do not have a delete option in teams admin in any of the two apps.
We are trying to test the activity notification and are unable to successfully test it because of this AAD App ID conflict. The same issue is happening with the Microsoft Teams Review team. Need help with fixing this issue as we need to keep both the apps.

If possible, use unique Teams Application IDs for each version of your app to help differentiate them within the admin center.

Thanks, Prasad, for your comment.
The error message is also saying to use Application ID for differentiating the apps. But where should I use the Application ID? I am not using any ID while calling the /sendActivityNotification API route. Do I need to use the Application ID while getting the access token? If yes, then how to pass it? Because I am not able to find any documentation from Microsoft about this.
Thanks again.

You might get an error if multiple Teams apps in the same scope (team, chat, or user) are using the same Microsoft Entra app. Make sure that you're using unique Microsoft Entra apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/send-activity-feed-notification?tabs=desktop#webapplicationinfo-update
